“Richard’s brothers are John and Geoffrey”
From Chapter 8 of the book Artificial intelligence: The modern approach:

“Richard’s brothers are John and Geoffrey”:
Brother (John, Richard) $∧$ Brother (Geoffrey, Richard) $∧$ John $\neq$ Geoffrey $∧$ ∀x Brother (x, Richard) ⇒ (x=John $∨$ x=Geoffrey)

Isn't translation this simpler, with the exact same meaning? If not, what is wrong with it?

∀x Brother (x, Richard) ⇒ ((x=John $∨$ x=Geoffrey) $∧$ John $\neq$ Geoffrey)

I don't believe that the book's answer is the only correct one, and that simpler translations don't exist.

EDIT
What's wrong with

Brother (John, Richard) ∧ Brother (Geoffrey, Richard) ∧ John ≠ Geoffrey

Does this mean that John and Geoffrey are two brothers of Richard but there can be more?

Your suggestion can be translated as "if Richard has a brother then it is either John or Geoffrey (and John is not Geoffrey)". You never say that Richard actually has John and Geoff as brothers.

Oh ThankYou so much, so I have to assert the brothers of Richard exist before I can claim that the two brothers are John and Geoffery. But then what's wrong with
"Brother (John, Richard) ∧ Brother (Geoffrey, Richard) ∧ John ≠ Geoffrey"
this alone? Does this mean that John and Geoffrey are two brothers of Richard but there can be more?

Exactly, the last part of the formula is what guarantees that there are no brothers other than John and Geoffrey

You could also write the propositional logic as
$$
\forall x \, (\text{Brother}(x, \text{Richard}) \iff (x = \text{John} \lor x = \text{Geoffrey})) \land \text{John} \neq \text{Geoffrey}
$$
The given expression is true if and only if ('iff') $x=\text{John}\lor \text{Geoffrey}$ (if $x$ is John or Geoffrey)
The distinctness condition between the two brothers John and Geoffrey remains separate as they both are distinct as this is global fact, not dependent on specific $x$.
Hope it Helps!
